# display tag slug as class per link in tag cloud

Tags: tags, filters, cloud

I would like to filter `wp_generate_tag_cloud` so each of the tag links include the slug as a class. More specifically, I would like to output "tag-" + the tag slug.

Currently what is assigned as the class is "tag-link-" + the tag ID.

The the end, I would happy with either a replacement or just adding this additional class to the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one possible way:
add a filter in functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter ( 'wp_tag_cloud', 'tag_cloud_slug_class' );

function tag_cloud_slug_class( $taglinks ) {
    $tags = explode('</a>', $taglinks);
    $regex = "#(.*tag-link[-])(.*)(' title.*)#e";
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tagn[] = preg_replace($regex, "('$1$2 tag-'.get_tag($2)->slug.'$3')", $tag );
        }
    $taglinks = implode('</a>', $tagn);
    return $taglinks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter on `wp_generate_tag_cloud_data`, it contains the class parameter and the tag slug, a filter(to address the question posted) might look something like.

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_tag_cloud_data', 'wpse_30049_wp_generate_tag_cloud_data' );
function wpse_30049_wp_generate_tag_cloud_data( $tags_data ) {
    foreach( $tags_data as $k => $tag )
        $tags_data[$k]->class = 'tag-cloud-link tag-'.$tag->slug;
        
    return $tags_data;
}
```

References:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_generate_tag_cloud_data/
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L990

Answer (score 0):

You can update the category-template.php file. In the $tags_data array, it lists all the tag attributes that are used to generate the tag cloud markup.

so you can change

```
'class'  => 'tag-cloud-link tag-link-' . $tag_id
```

to

```
'class' => 'tag-cloud-link tag-link-' . $tag_slug
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).